# wvetutil event parsing for errors in last few events

Tags: windows, events

I am using wevtutil to get the last 10 logs in windows servers, with this simple command.

`wevtutil qe Application /rd:false /c:10 /f:text`

So can I parse events like: all the error events in last 10 logs.

Answer (score 1):

this will list the lasts 10 errors:

```
wevtutil qe application "/q:*[System[(Level=1 or Level=2 )]]" /c:10 /f:text /rd:true
```

**be carefull the Xpath query is case sensitive**

Comment: this I already know, but this is not what I need. I need to filter the errors from last 10 events. So I have to get all the last 10 events and again find the error events in those 10. Bcoz the last 10 error may have happened before few years.

Comment: Are you able to run powershell scripts ? Otherwise a dirty way could be to get the xml format then use findstr to check for error `wevtutil qe application /c:10 /f:xml /rd:true |findstr "error"`

Comment: @Kayasaz. I tried this also. But its hiding the rest of the information what I get in initial query. I cant run Powershell script.

Comment: Thanks Kayasax. Instead of using "error", I used "<Level>2</Level>" with findstr, to get what I needed. But with the output in xml now, it took lot of formatting to get the correct texts.

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to parse XML with batch. It would be very easy with powershell.